# Where should javah fit into an SBT build?

Tags: scala, sbt

[`javah`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html) is used to generate C headers from [`@native`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/native.html) methods. It operates on compiled class files, so it requires a classpath as an argument. For this reason, it seems sensible to make a `javah` task depend on [`fullClasspath`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/sxr/sbt/Keys.scala.html#sbt.Keys.fullClasspath)`in Compile`.

The issue I am facing is that the generated headers are needed in order to build a native library, and the native library needs to be a resource. But, because it is a resource, it will be included in `fullClasspath in Compile`, which leads to a circular dependency.

Does SBT have a classpath key that includes all `.class` files but excludes resources?

Comment: Does it matter if the native library is in classpath or not? Doesn't javah only search for .class files?

Comment: @thirstycrow Yes, you are right, the native library does not need to be in the classpath for `javah`. The tricky part is that I need to obtain the classpath from SBT, and SBT will include the native library automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered [sbt-jni](https://github.com/jodersky/sbt-jni), a very interesting new SBT plugin which simplifies working with JNI from SBT.

When reading some source code, I stumbled over
[this line](https://github.com/jodersky/sbt-jni/blob/8f6744e548466bc65bd51b022bbaa66f6850de97/plugin/src/main/scala/ch/jodersky/sbt/jni/plugins/JniJavah.scala#L43)
, which seems to refer to the problem you are facing. If I understand it correctly, the work-around in sbt-jni is to combine `dependencyClasspath in Compile`, `compile in Compile`, and `classDirectory in Compile` instead of using `fullClasspath in Compile`. I'm not sure if this will exactly result in a classpath that includes all `.class` files, but maybe something like that works for you as well.

Comment: Yes, this turns out to be a good way of getting the classpath.